How can I fix the problem that I can't find sound settings from spotlight search in macOS?
Device: Apple M2 Max, macOS: 15.1 (24B83)
I need to adjust my Sound preference due to work. It used to be all good. I can quickly access sound settings by entering "sound" in the spotlight search.
But recently, I have encountered troubles.
Fail to find sound settings in spotlight search
A few weeks ago, I can't find sound settings from spotlight search.

So I have to go to system settings. A few more clicks, I can bear with it anyway.
Fail to find sound in settings search.
And today, I suddenly can't find "Sound" in the search panel of system settings. It used to be good yesterday.

Though I can access it by clicking the Sound on the sidebar, it's so inconvenient, a lot of more clicks compared to the spotlight search access.

Is there anything I can do to fix it?
Update:
I have checked the Spotlight option and I am sure everything is checked.
What else can I do?


Have you tried re-indexing Spotlight? If you need to access the Sound panel quickly, you can just hold Option while pressing a volume button (F11 - F12).

Thanks, Opt+F11 is a cool way, but I have checked the Spotlight indexing, I have every options checked (please see updated OP), I don't now what else can I do to force it to index.

Have you followed these steps: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/102321  ?? Add your entire Macintosh HD volume to the privacy window, and then remove it.

Yes. But it says: "Drag the disk or folder you want to re-index to the list of locations that Spotlight is prevented from searching in." - I don't know how do I drag the "Sound Settings" here.

See my previous comment. Add the whole disk. (You will have to wait until it has re-indexed the drive.)
